# Dynamic filtering with ConversationalRetrievalChain

Tags: langchain

I'm trying to add metadata filtering of the underlying vector store (`chroma`).

```py
db = Chroma.from_documents(texts, embeddings)
```

It works like this:

```py
qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    OpenAI(openai_api_key=get_random_key(OPENAI_API_KEY_POOL), cache=True, temperature=0),
    VectorStoreRetriever(vectorstore=db, search_kwargs={"filter": {"source": "data/my.pdf"}}),
    verbose=True,
    return_source_documents=True) 
result = qa({"question": query, "chat_history": []})
```

But this would imply creating a separate chain for each document which seems weird. However, when I try to pass the filter to the existing chain, it doesn't seem to have any effect, it returns results for all the documents in the db.

```py
qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    OpenAI(openai_api_key=get_random_key(OPENAI_API_KEY_POOL), cache=True, temperature=0),
    VectorStoreRetriever(vectorstore=db),
    verbose=True,
    return_source_documents=True)

filter = {'source': 'my.pdf'}

result = qa({"question": query, "chat_history": [], "filter": filter})
```

Am I missing something? Or it really won't work without extending the existing classes/modifying source code of `langchain`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up extending both classes I used to pass the filter:

```py
class ConversationalRetrievalChainPassArgs(ConversationalRetrievalChain):

    def _get_docs(self, question: str, inputs: Dict[str, Any], *,
        run_manager: CallbackManagerForChainRun) -> List[Document]:
        """Get docs."""
        docs = self.retriever._get_relevant_documents(
            question, inputs['filter']
        )
        return self._reduce_tokens_below_limit(docs)


class VectorStoreRetrieverWithFiltering(VectorStoreRetriever):

    def _get_relevant_documents(self, query: str, filter: dict) -> List[Document]:
        if self.search_type == "similarity":
            docs = self.vectorstore.similarity_search(query, filter=filter, **self.search_kwargs)
        ...
        return docs
```

If anyone has a more elegant solution, please share.

Answer (score 1):

My vector database is `OpenSearch` so in terms of filtering with `Chroma` I'm not sure if this will be totally relevant, but it looks like a similar implementation in any case:

```py
qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    llm=model,
    retriever=vectorStore.as_retriever(
        search_kwargs={
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "metadata.language": {
                            "value": query_string_params["language"],
                            "case_insensitive": True,
                        }
                    },
                },
            ],
        )
)
```

Comment: Thanks this helped but how to pass values:
class RagQAInput(TypedDict):
    question: str
    category: str
    language: Optional[str]

search_kwargs={
                    "filter": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "metadata.category": {
                                    "value": "",
                                    "case_insensitive": True,
                                }
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                }

Comment: @Javed can't you just pass the value in the `"value"` entry? The example you show is blank (`""`)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78135564/how-to-pass-dynamic-filter-to-the-vector-retriever-of-the-chain-from-the-input here is the complete question