# How to pass dynamic filter to the vector retriever of the chain from the input (request body) in langchain?

Tags: langchain, opensearch

```py
class RagQAInput(TypedDict):
    question: str
    category: str
    language: Optional[str]

docs_vectorstore = OpenSearchVectorSearch(
    opensearch_url=get_opensearch_url(),
    index_name="docs",
    embedding_function=embeddings_function,
    # vector_field="invoice_desc_vec",
    # text_field="invoice_desc",
    http_compress=True,
    use_ssl=False,
    verify_certs=False,  # DONT USE IN PRODUCTION
    ssl_assert_hostname=False,
    ssl_show_warn=False,
    bulk_size=2000,  # default is 500
)

docs_chain = (
    RunnableParallel(
        context=(
            itemgetter("question")
            | docs_vectorstore.as_retriever(
                search_kwargs={
                    "filter": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "metadata.category": {
                                    "value": f"{itemgetter('category')}",
                                    "case_insensitive": True,
                                }
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                }
            )
        ),
        question=itemgetter("question"),
        language=itemgetter("language"),
    )
    | RunnableParallel(
        answer=(ANSWER_PROMPT | llm_for_qa_client), docs=itemgetter("context")
    )
).with_types(input_type=RagQAInput)
```

This is resulting in the error:

```
opensearchpy.exceptions.SerializationError: 
({'size': 4, 'query': {'bool': {'filter': [{'term': {'metadata.category': {'value': operator.itemgetter('category'), 'case_insensitive': True}
```

Comment: What is `itemgetter`? It looks like `opensearchpy` is having trouble with the data type since `itemgetter` is just some kind of `object`. Have you tried replacing the values with `strings`? Or maybe there is some method for the `itemgetter()` object to get a `string` value.

Comment: it works with string value, but I want to get the value from client, request body params, It is a langchain thing, I have some idea now. It should be passed as config: https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/data_connection/retrievers/ensemble. I will make this work and share the answer.